# Laravel - too few arguments

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to setup a simple button to update a db column value when clicked. I can't seem to figure out why my route isn't getting passed my value however?

HTML:

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ route('approveResturant') }}">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $resturant->id }}" />
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">
    Approve
  </button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```html
public function approveResturant($request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
        $id = $request->id;
        $resturant = Resturant::find($id);
        $resturant->approved = 1;
        $resturant->save;

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Resturant Approved Successfully!');
    }
```

Route:
`Route::post('approveResturant'[ResturantController::class,'approveResturant'])->middleware(['auth'])->name('approveResturant');`

And finally, the error itself:
[image: Error Message]

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `Request` type-hint to your function:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function approveResturant(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
    $id = $request->id;
    $resturant = Resturant::find($id);
    $resturant->approved = 1;
    $resturant->save;

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Resturant Approved Successfully!');
}
```

The difference here is that Laravel understands the `Request` type-hint and knows that **it** should inject the `Request` object from the pre-defined services it has in its [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container). Otherwise, Laravel doesn't know where that parameter is coming from so assumes **you** will provide it. Simply naming your parameter `$request` is insufficient.

**Update**

> Do you know why the function would still not be saving the new approved value to the DB?

A few potential reasons:

1. You have not removed the `dd($request->all());` statement
2. `$resturant = Resturant::find($id);` failed to find a record in the database
3. `save` is a function not a property so `$resturant->save;` should be `$resturant->save();`

To isolate the exact issue you will need to perform some debugging (e.g. either using xdebug or `dd` statements).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why the function would still not be saving the new approved value to the DB?

Comment: @swamptiger24 I have updated my answer with some suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Use Request Class

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function approveResturant(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
    $id = $request->id;
    $resturant = Resturant::find($id);
    $resturant->approved = 1;
    $resturant->save;

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Resturant Approved Successfully!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why the function would still not be saving the new approved value to the DB?

Comment: remove dd($request->all());

Comment: even without, no change

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('restaurant.approveResturant') }}">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $resturant->id }}" />
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">
    Approve
  </button>
</form>
```

```
Route::post("/restaurant/store", [RestaurantController::class, "approveResturant"])->name("restaurant.approveResturant");
```

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function approveResturant(Request $request)
{
    $restaurant = Restaurant::where("id", $request->input("id"))->update([
        "approved" => 1
    ]);

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Restaurant Approved Successfully!');
}
```